# How do I stop the text on my flashcards from overshooting the area?

Tags: formatting

This is not using the `flashcards` class because that does not print the cards in a way that I want them to be printed. That is why it is a modified article class. I have recently tried a set this up with `beamer` and it gives me the same problem but it is easier to configure the font size with `beamer`.

I added `float` package but I wasn't sure how to implement it in order to solve this problem and the texdoc for `float` is like another language altogether. It is stopping me from being able to print long questions so very limiting. Any suggestions would be welcome.

```
documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=.47\paperwidth,paperheight=.25\paperheight]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\pgfpagesuselayout{8 on 1}[a4paper]        
\makeatletter
\@tempcnta=1\relax
\loop\ifnum\@tempcnta<9\relax
\pgf@pset{\the\@tempcnta}{bordercode}{\pgfusepath{stroke}}

\advance\@tempcnta by 1\relax
\repeat
\makeatother


\newenvironment{flashcard}[2][]{%
\noindent   \textsc{#1}
\vfill
\centerline{{\noindent  \Large{#2}}}
\vfill
\newpage
\noindent  
}
{\newpage}

\begin{document}




\begin{flashcard}[Statistical Mechanics]{What is the equilibrium entropy of an isolated system of N constituents with energy E? }
What is the equilibrium entropy of an isolated system of N constituents with energy E?
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}
$$S(N, E) = k ln \Omega(N, E, {\alpha*})$$
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}

\end{flashcard}

\end{document}
```

Here is what the problem looks like:

[image: flashcard]

Comment: `\centerline` makes an unsplittable box.

Comment: I also tried doing my own cards a while ago and wrote this package https://github.com/kellertuer/Kartei - maybe it might fit your needs, though the manual is still only available in german, i hadn't had the time to translate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `\centerline` which makes a box that can't be broken across lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
  paperwidth=.47\paperwidth,
  paperheight=.25\paperheight
  ]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}

\pgfpagesuselayout{8 on 1}[a4paper]        
\makeatletter
\@tempcnta=1\relax
\loop\ifnum\@tempcnta<9\relax
\pgf@pset{\the\@tempcnta}{bordercode}{\pgfusepath{stroke}}

\advance\@tempcnta by 1\relax
\repeat
\makeatother

\newenvironment{flashcard}[2][]
  {\noindent\textsc{#1}\par\vfill
   {\centering\Large#2\par}
   \vfill
   \newpage\noindent\ignorespaces
  }
  {\newpage}

\begin{document}

\begin{flashcard}[Statistical Mechanics]
  {What is the equilibrium entropy of an isolated system of 
   $N$~constituents with energy~$E$?}
What is the equilibrium entropy of an isolated system of 
$N$~constituents with energy~$E$?
\vfill
\[
S(N, E) = k \ln \Omega(N, E, {\alpha*})
\]
\vfill
\end{flashcard}

\end{document}
```

[image]